# Rails 3.2 unknown unknown attribute: author_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I want to add Authors to my Articles and:

```
unknown attribute: author_id
```

controller:

```
    def create
  @article = current_user.articles.new(params[:article])
  @article.save
flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Posted!"
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
```

model1:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!
  has_many :articles
  validates_confirmation_of :password, message: "should match confirmation", if: :password
end
```

model2:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :body, :tag_list, :image 
belongs_to :author
has_many :taggings
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
has_attached_file :image, :default_url => '/no_image.jpg'

end
```

And sadly i have no idea whats wrong

////

> In Article model you should use author_id because Author has many
>   Article. user_id will be used to point each article to a particular
>   author

now i got this:

```
uninitialized constant Article::AuthorId
```

Comment: Please verify in your db/schema.rb that articles has an "author_id" column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the author_id to your database table by a migration:

```
class AddAuthorToArticle < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :author_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add author_id to your attr_accessible list.

Answer (score 1):

In Article model you should use author_id because Author has many Article. user_id will be used to point each article to a particular author

Answer (score 1):

Add `authors_attributes` to your `attr_accessible` in you Author model. Make sure you have also references columns in migrations.

In your Articles migration you should have a line like this:

```
t.references :author
```